# Javascript to Excel: bad performance for lack of "range" method

Tags: javascript, excel

Considering that you use Internet Explorer only (which is often the case in large enterprises), you conclude that you may offer to your users the possibility to transform an HTML gridview into an Excel file: Moreover, you simply consider that you have to do it in so far as the users ask for it...

The first experience I had with writing tables(or arrays) to Excel from the outside was with Visual Basic (the server side of .net). So I wrote a class to spread a VB 2D-array into an Excel sheet:

1) The first method I used seemed good at first sight and, by the way, it was quite simple: set a loop on columns inside a loop on rows, and write each value from the VB array to the Excel sheet. So it goes:

```
        Dim j, k as Integer
        Dim Valeur as String
        'let us suppose the VB 2D-array is "Tab(10,20)", containing 11 rows of 21 columns of strings
        'let us suppose the upper left corner of the Excel range is line 7, column 3:
        For j = 0 to 10
           For k = 0 to 20
             Valeur = Tab(j, k)
             Cells(j + 7, k + 3).Value = valeur
           Next
        Next
```

2) Having programmed the above method , I realized in the end that, though it was simple and logical, it was a bad method, for just one reason: **IT IS AWFULLY SLOW!**
So I found a better method, consisting of writing the whole range of cells at once:

```
                Feuil.Range("C7:W17").Value = Tab
```

What difference between first and second method? Well, both methods work correctly, but if you consider a table of 300 rows of 20 columns (or 6000 cells), the time taken by the first method will be around 1 minute, meanwhile the second one takes only half a second!

So, when it came to JavaScript, I tried the same methods: first, open an Excel-ActiveX object (in MS-IE, of course), that gives access to the Excel Object Model Reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149081(v=office.12).aspx) with which I can apply the first method as follows, using a CSV stack set in an object called 'ap':

```
   // 'ap' is a Javascript object holding a table of CSV strings (natural index: 1..n)
   var valCell;         
   var lim = ap.nbChamps;  // 'nbChamps'= number of csv columns in 'ap' object        
   var curLig = 6;         // the datas are written to lines 7 and under        
   for (var j = 1; j <= ap.nbelem; j++) // ap.nbelem= number of lines in 'ap'
   {   // lines loop            
      curLig += 1;            
      for (var k = 1; k <= lim; k++)  // N.B: 'ap' uses natural index: 1 to n and not 0 to n-1
      {   // columns loop                
        valCell = ap.litEnLC(j, k);  // 'ap' method reading column k from line j              
        classeur.ActiveSheet.Cells(curLig, k + 2 ).value = valCell;                              
      }        
    }
```

Having used that method, I found the same slowness again: So, I wanted to transpose the second method to javascript, as follows:
. Firstly, add a method to the "ap" object, that converts the CSV stack into a Javascript 2D-array
. Secondly, write this 2D-array into the "range" object, just as I did in Visual Basic. So:

```
    // 'zone' is the range. For example: zone= "C7:W17"
    var biTab = ap.pcttEnTab(); // converts CSV stack into a 2D-array
    classeur.ActiveSheet.Range(zone).value = biTab;
```

And, as expected, this goes much faster, but the problem is it doesn't really work, because instead of transferring each value of the 2D-Array to the corresponding cell of the Excel range, **it writes the whole Javascript 2D-array in every cell of the Excel range!**

So the problem is: How to write a Javascript 2D-Array into an Excel range at once?

Thanks to anyone who can give me the answer...

By the way, I'm adding the pcttEnTab method just in case someone could fine an explanation of my problem in that method:

```
this.pcttEnTab = function ()    // Array (tableau à 2 dimensions)
{   // convertit la pile PCTT en tableau à 2 dimensions         
    var j, k, s;
    var biTab = new Array();
    for (k = 0; k < this.nbelem; k++) // create a columns Array for each line
    {
        biTab[k] = new Array();
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= this.nbelem; j++)  // lines loop (natural index)
    {
        for (k = 1; k <= this.nbChamps; k++) // columns loop
        {
            s = this.litEnLC(j, k);
            biTab[j - 1][k - 1] = s;
        }
    }
    return biTab
}
```

Comment: Perhaps part of the problem is that JavaScript doesn't have 2D arrays? (Just arrays of arrays.)

Comment: Hey! You are spamming SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484058/write-javascript-2d-table-to-excel-sheet

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry but I was so deceived to get no answer the first time, that I thought maybe I wasn't clear enough, and also made a few mistakes in copying different parts of the code. This problem being important to me, I decided to try a second chance. I'm now sudying your keen suggestions, hoping to make it work at last... Thansk you by the way for your interesting answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the JavaScript array to a native array.
One way to do this is with the Dictionary object, see http://cwestblog.com/2011/10/24/javascript-snippet-array-prototype-tovbarray:

```
var dict = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.Dictionary');
for (var i=0;i < 5; i++ ) dict.add(i,i);
sheet.cells(1,1).resize(5, 1).value = sheet.application.Transpose(dict.items());
```

If you write to a row, ommit the *Transpose()*.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this interesting article from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286315/en-us) explaining a few interactions between `ActiveSheet.Range` and JavaScript arrays. They mention a "workaround using `SafeArray`"... maybe this can help.

Comment: Can you please find the explanation for why `[]` doesn't create a "true" array? Certainly `[] instanceof Array` is `true`...

Comment: I tried to find the reference, but I couldn't. And it seems the explanation is my bad memory. From what I researched now, the difference may happen with other data types, not arrays. Specially strings can cause confusion, because they may be string literals (primitives) or string objects (instances).

Comment: @nnnnnn: thanks for the comment. I have "refactored" my answer!

Comment: Well, if it can help, here's the code of the "pcttEnTab" method: